# Obtener name array php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hola que tal compañeros tengo la siguiente duda tengo tengo el siguiente array que obtengo al realizar una consulta en php uso los servicios de google para traducir como podria setear el resultado en el campo que corresponde

```
$content = [$tour->name, $tour->ciidad, $tour->schedulle, $tour->puntoInicio];
        // Translate text .

        foreach ($content as $traduccion) {
            $result = $translate->translate($traduccion, [
                'target' => $lenguaje
            ]);
             $traduccion = $result['text'];
        }
```

Por ejemplo deberia quedar asi pero quiero saber si lo puedo hacer desde el foreach

```
$tour->name = 'Hola mundo';
$tour->ciudad= 'Mexico';
```

Comment: Quieres reemplazar los valores de los atributos en el objeto que tienes en `$tour`?

Comment: asi es quiero sobreescribir el contenido d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear un arreglo asociativo (`array(clave => valor)`) donde:

- la *clave* representa el nombre del campo
- el *valor* es el texto a traducir.

Luego en el `foreach` usas la *clave* para saber en que propiedad hay que guardar el resultado.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$content = [
    'name' => $tour->name,
    'ciudad' => $tour->ciudad,
    'schedulle' => $tour->schedulle,
    'puntoInicio' => $tour->puntoInicio,
];

// Translate text .
foreach ($content as $key => $value) {
    $result = $translate->translate($value, [
        'target' => $lenguaje
    ]);

    // ACA pisamos el valor de la propiedad
    $tour->{$key} = $result['text'];
}
```

Comment: Gracias me funcione perfectamente